# Is there function in spark just like mapreduce's cleanup function in hadoop?

Tags: apache-spark

Is there function in **Spark** just like mapreduce's ***cleanup()*** function in hadoop? If there isn't, how to know the end of the task?

There is a demand: when the task process data of the last one or last row (the data will be process one by one, isn't it?), I need to execute some custom code or customized behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to invoke `SparkContext.stop()` at the end of your job. But in case you want to have some customized behavior like ensuring that connection are closed than you have to write custom code for achieving the same.

Invoking `SparkContext.stop()` will cleanup/ destroy/ release all resources used claimed by the specific Spark Job.

There is also a `SparkContext.isStopped` which returns true in case SparkContext is destroyed or in process of destroying. Refer API [Here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext)

Comment: what if i forgot to call sc.stop(), will it releases all resources automatically?

Comment: I update my question just now, could you help me again? Thank a lot!

Comment: @Shankar - yes it will release the resources but it is always a good practice to call up stop explicitly.

Comment: @Guo - You will never know which is the last one, because partitions are processed in parallel. Unless you specify some dependency upon the code, there will be nothing called "processing last row". May be you can elaborate the need and intended functionality and I can try to provide some solution.

Comment: @Sumit Thank you for you help! I find the way to achieve the demand. Using _mapPartitions()_ I can get all elements in each partition, and then I will know which element is the last element in each partititon.